# Codeigniter with CSRF protection and multipart/formdata request header

Tags: javascript, ajax, codeigniter, csrf

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var temp = "csrf_test_name="+document.getElementsByName("csrf_test_name")[0].value;

xhr.open("POST", "upload", true);

xhr.onreadystatechange=function(){
    if (xhr.readyState==4 && xhr.status==200){
            console.log(xhr.responseText);
    }
} 

xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhr.send(temp);
```

The above code works and does not result in a 500 error (for csrf failure). I want to upload files so I need to change the Request Header to the following:

```
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
```

When I do this it fails the csrf check. I have seen other suggestions that involve turning off the csrf for uploads but would prefer not to do this. Is there away to leave it enabled and upload these files?